# webpack loading bootstrap before jquery and popper

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4

i can not figure out why, my new laravel installation with ui bootstrap, is loading bootstrap before jquery and popper, which means stuff like bootstrap toogle dosent work. The builded js file has first bootstrap then jquery and last popper, anyone has an idea why it is doing that?

Comment: Check the order of the js build, it could be webpack or something out there.

Comment: I'm not an expert on how webpack works, but the build js file dossent have the same order as they are difined in webpack, but it still works. As commented before, the bug came from the shipped with jquery version, which now is fixed with the latest version of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the current laravel jquery vesion has a bug. The latest jquery vesion 3.5.1 fixes it, so running:
npm install jquery@3.5.1 
npm run dev 
should work.